# Accessing public/private methods of a jQuery widget from within an .each() method inside that widget

Tags: jquery, scope, widget, each

I'm trying to extend the Tabs widget in jQuery so that it automatically adds certain html to a tab upon either the creation of a new tab (triggered by user) or on page load (for any pre-existing tabs).  I was able to get all of this to work external to the widget by using the regular tabs widget and a bunch of custom javascript functions.  However, to make it more modular, I want those functions to be member functions of my extended widget.

**Widget:**

```
$.widget( "custom.extendedTabs", $.ui.tabs, {
    ,_addOptions: function($el) {
        //add a "close" button and an "options" button on each tab on mouseover
    }   
    ,_create: function() {
        this.element.find("li").each(function(i,el){
            this._addOptions($(this));
        });
        return this._super();
    }
    ,addTab: function() {
        //handle tab creation
        ........
        this._addOptions(<newlyCreatedliElement>);
    }
});
```

**Instantiation:**

```
$(".tabs").each(function(){
    $(this).extendedTabs();
});
```

**Sample:**

```
<div id="tabs1" class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tabs2" class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The Problem:**

Based on testing I have no problem calling `this._addOptions()` directly from `_create()`.  However, I do not have the same success when calling it from the `.each()` inside of `_create()`.  When attempting to do so, I receive `this.addOptions is not a function` as an error.

I know that the `this` inside of the `.each()` represents the iterated instance element, itself, and not the parent widget that called it.  But I thought there might be some way to reference the object that called the `.each()`.

**UPDATE:**

I was successfully able to replace the `.each()` with the following:

```
for (var el in this.element.find("li").toArray()) {
    this._addOptions($(this.element.find("li").toArray()[el]));
}
```

It feels clunky, however, so I would still appreciate some insight from somebody who may have a cleaner method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've considered an alternate solution -- one that retains the jQuery `.each()`:

```
,_create: function() {
    var self=this;
    this.element.find("li").each(function(i,el){
        self._addOptions($(this));
    });
    return this._super();
}
```